# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when I add external JARs using Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am new to Java and Eclipse. I tried to add external jar files and import class in it but failed.

The code that import class in a jar file, new an instance and call a function of the object is shown below:

```java
import cn.Hello;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello h = new Hello();
        h.hello();
    }
}
```

The Eclipse IDE doesn't throw any error. But when I run with Eclipse, it threw:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cn/Hello
    at Test.main(Test.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cn.Hello
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

And the project I built on Eclipse is like this:

[image: The project I built]

Could you please help to solve it?

p.s

```sh
❯ find .
.
./.DS_Store
./bin
./bin/Test.class
./.classpath
./.gitignore
./.project
./src
./src/Test.java

❯ jar tf /Users/fxb/Desktop/test.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
cn/Hello.class
cn/edu/Hello.class
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Eclipse cannot access `test.jar`. It has no permission.

Comment: @g00se I am using Mac OS.

Comment: @RomanC Can I give it permission to access `test.jar`?

Comment: Please change to the project directory in Terminal and post the output of `find`

Comment: @g00se I have posted the output of `find` in my question.

Comment: Class `Hello` doesn't exist. You're going to have to recreate it in the correct package

Comment: you can give it permission what permition has it

Comment: @g00se But I have added an external jar file.

Comment: OK, can you post output of
`jar tf /Users/fxb/Desktop/test.jar`

Comment: @g00se I have posted.

Comment: @RomanC I have given permission to Eclipse but it doesn't work.

Comment: Strange. Make `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));` the first line of your code and let us know what it prints

Comment: @g00se It prints `/Users/fxb/Desktop/Java-Programming/Codes/bin`.

Comment: So that's showing the jar is not in the classpath, hence your problem. I don't use Eclipse but despite your image above, it seems not to have put the jar in the runtime classpath

Comment: `java -cp /Users/fxb/Desktop/Java-Programming/Codes/bin:/Users/fxb/Desktop/test.jar Test` should run your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I figured out that I add the external jar file to the module path but not the class path. So the Eclipse IDE didn't throw any error but at run time Java threw `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. After I have added the jar to the class path, it's OK. It's in: **right click the project** -> `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Libraries` -> `Classpath` -> `Add external JARs`.